# How can I validate if my license.xml supports XM Cloud?

Tags: xm-cloud, license

I have a partner `license.xml` file for `Sitecore 10`, is there a way to quickly tell just by looking at the `license.xml` content if `XM Cloud` is supported? In the past there was `Sitecore.JSS` but I am not sure if this is still the case now as I cannot see this in my license?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any separate license file to run XM Cloud in your local environment. All you need access to the XMCloud with your account, and your account must be an admin account. While doing the setup you need to login using powershell script, that will verify your access.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the partner license does not extend to the XM Cloud platform. However, as a Sitecore partner, you have the opportunity to request access to the XM Cloud `sandbox environment`, which allows for practical `experimentation` and `testing` purposes. Please have a try.

Comment: We are in process of getting access to sandbox but I cannot setup the local environment without Sandbox up and running and the valid license. So I just wanted to verify that the license I got is the right one when we receive access to the sandbox.